# Strange redraw? issue html app in webview on android

Tags: android, html, css, webview, drawable

I made a simple nixie clock html app and wrap it in a WebView to use on android. No fancy stuff. Just one HTML file, a JS file and a css file (and ten digit images).

After a couple of hours there are stripes in the center of the screen (where the animation is and beyond) and the screen is completely unreadable. Also the menu is 'damaged' because a portion of the screen is corrupted. See picture below (excuses for the bad quality of these pictures = webcam):

[image]

Is this a known bug? After a restart of the app everything shows up normal again.

The device I'm using is an Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 running on Android 4.3 I9300BUUGNF1

To animate the numbers I created a script that sets a class on the container with 10 digits in it to show one number. All images are completely transparant (opacity:0) when no class is set. This is because I'm using an ease transition of 250ms to give it a nice in-out fade (to opacity:1).

Is there a problem with using CSS3 features?
This is the css:

```
.nixie,.clock       { position:fixed; width:80%; height:80%; text-align:center; margin:0 10%;  }
.clock              { top:36px; }
.clock .digit       { display:inline-block; min-height:800px; width:12.2%; margin-top:8%; padding:0; font-size:0; overflow:hidden; background:#000 url(../img/nixietube.png) top center no-repeat; background-size:100%; }
.clock .digit img   { opacity:0; position:absolute; width:12%; margin-left:-2.4%; margin-top:0.2%; }
.clock .digit img.dot { margin-left:1.8%; margin-top:-0.2%; } 

body.seg6 .clock .digit.seg8    { display:none; }
body.seg6 .clock .digit         { width:16.6%;  margin:0; margin-top:8%; }
body.seg6 .clock .digit img     { width:16%; margin-top:0; margin-left:-3.2%; }
body.seg6 .clock .digit img.dot { margin-left:1.8%; margin-top:-0.1%; } 


.clock .digit.d0 img.d0, 
.clock .digit.d1 img.d1, 
.clock .digit.d2 img.d2, 
.clock .digit.d3 img.d3, 
.clock .digit.d4 img.d4, 
.clock .digit.d5 img.d5, 
.clock .digit.d6 img.d6, 
.clock .digit.d7 img.d7, 
.clock .digit.d8 img.d8, 
.clock .digit.d9 img.d9, 
.clock .digit.dot img.dot,
.clock .digit.slash img.slash { opacity:1; -moz-transition: all 250ms ease; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you produce a fiddle?

Comment: See my answer MastaBaba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is not free of bugs, for sure, especially older versions of the OS/SDK. The problem was a combination of things. At first I create the WebView dynamically and set some settings. I also use a bitmap (ImageView) as some kind of splashscreen. So when the WebView is created it covers the ImageView. This slowdown the response of the WebView (because the ImageView is still visible) and caused also another problem like the soft keyboard won't popup.

Because of the slow response of the WebView and the stutter animations, I decided to apply some hardware or software accelaration by using `WebView.setLayerType`.

The software version `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` is not free of bugs. It **cannot handle transparency without strange side effects (glitches)** like a image with transparancy, a background with transparency or transparancy on transparency. It also have problems with absolute placed elements that can be scrolled (appear on wrong position). When I turned of the software accelaration and hide the splash bitmap, everything went back to normal.

There was also an error in the code to decide to apply software/hardware acceleration, so I changed it to this:

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) // HONEYCOMB instead of KITKAT
    { 
        this.webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }
    else {
            // UPDATE: DO NOTHING, BUGS IN SOFTWARE LAYER
            // older android version, enable software acceleration
            //this.webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
         }
```

I changed the CSS for Android WebView, no or less transparency and no (CSS) animations because the WebView is too slow for this even when hardware accelaration is used. So be careful using fancy stuff.

It is really sad that the WebView is of that bad quality, it must be the same as the Android stock browser but it is in some ways very different. If you want to avoid all these troubles and you are able to target your software for KITKAT or higher, you can use the WebView based upon Chrome (see also: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview). Chrome WebViews include an updated version of the V8 JavaScript engine and support for modern web standards previously missing in older WebViews.